# Getting a local variable referenced before before assignment error in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a threaded timer that will increment a variable every 1 second. The variable is located in the callback function and is queried in a serial receive function in order to set up a timeout if no data is received in a prescribed time. The callback function as well as the receive function both have the variable declared as global as well as the variable being declared outside of the timer class. Whenever the callback is triggered, the assignment error is displayed. Not sure what I am doing wrong in order to fix this error.

```
# python27 Serial Interface Prototype - MH 20170711
__author__ = 'MHammersley'

from serial import *
import threading

gRdTimeout = 0
t = None

class Cmd_Resp(object):

    # opens a usb-to-serial com port session at the specified baud rate
    def __init__(self, serial_port, baud, delimiter = '/n'):
        #ensure non-blocking
        self.serial_port = serial_port
        self.baud = baud
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.port = Serial(serial_port, baud, timeout = 0, writeTimeout=0)
        global t
        self.t = threading.Timer(1.0, self.UpdateTimer).start()

    # this function updates the timer variable in 1 second increments
    def UpdateTimer(self):
        global gRdTimeout
        gRdTimeOut += 1
        print('Count: ', gRdTimeout)

    def start(self):
        global t
        self.t.start() # start the timer

    # write only command, no read response
    def send(self, cmd):
        #Write command to com port
        self.port.write(cmd+self.delimiter)

    # read only until the expected response string is received
    def receive(self, exp_resp, timeout):
        #Read device response from com port.
        global gRdTimeout, t 
        gRdTimeOut = 0 # set the timeout count to 0
        serBuffer = "" # empty the buffer
        tflag = True
        self.t.start() # start the timer
        loop = True
        while (loop != False):
            c = self.port.read()
            if c == '\n':
                serBuffer += "\n" # add the newline to the buffer
            else:
                serBuffer += c # add to the buffer
            if exp_resp in serBuffer:
                loop = False
            if gRdTimeout >= timeout:
                break
        self.t.cancel() # stop the timer
        return serBuffer

    # sends a command to the uut and reads until the expected response is received
    def request(self, cmd, exp_resp):
        self.send(cmd)
        self.exp_resp = exp_resp
        return self.receive(exp_resp)
```

Comment: Stop using so many `global` variables

Comment: Please post a full traceback. This question is incomplete without one.

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
def UpdateTimer(self):
    global gRdTimeout # lowercase O
    gRdTimeOut += 1   # capital O
    print('Count: ', gRdTimeout)
```

That said, you should really avoid using global variables like this. Especially as you've already gone to the trouble of encapsulating this into a class. Set a timeout max when you call `receive` based on `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeout)`, then on every check just see if `datetime.datetime.now()` is earlier or later than the cutoff.

```
def receive(self, exp_resp, timeout):
    cutoff = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeout)
    serBuffer = ""
    tflag = True  # doesn't seem to be used here -- what is this for??
    while datetime.datetime.now() <= cutoff:
        c = self.port.read()
        serBuffer += c # add to the buffer
        if exp_resp in serBuffer:
            return serBuffer
    return None  # or do you want a partial buffer return after timeout expires?
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, your suggestion was a big help and provided a very simple solution to what I was trying to do. I implemented your solution into my code and it works as intended. Again, thanks for the quick response and help!

Comment: @Mikeehamm glad it helped! If this solved your problem, please consider clicking the green checkmark below the voting buttons. This selects my answer as the "Accepted" answer for this question. It also awards both you and I some reputation. If you'd rather hold out for a more direct answer to your question, please feel free to do so -- the "Accept" checkmark is purely an arbitrary designation by the question-asker.